# Copying files to clipboard from shell

Tags: linux, command-line, clipboard

How do I copy files (e.g. pictures) to clipboard using bash so that I can paste them into other programs?

If I view an image in Firefox and right click and copy the image, then I can directly paste it into other program like for example telegram using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to send the image.
I would like to have that functionality that I could do that from bash too.

I tried using

```
cat image.png | xclip -selection c
```

when I then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in telegram, it pastes

```
� PNG
```

as text instead of pasting the image.

Using `xclip-copyfile` does not work either, it does not change the content of the clipboard that is used when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in telegram at all.

Comment: Does copying the file's full path & name work "good enough"?

Answer (score 0):

```
xclip -selection clipboard -t "$(file -b --mime-type "$img")" < "$img"
```

Comment: Although this may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain why and/or how it addresses the issue. Providing this additional context would significantly improve its long-term educational value. Please edit your answer to add explanation, including the parameters and what limitations and assumptions apply.  Thanks.