# How to copy selected image/screenshot to clipboard?

Tags: linux, images, arch-linux, clipboard

I'm currently using Manjaro but I'd like something that'd work on Arch too for future migration. I'm using i3 at the moment but plan to switch to dwm.

To put a screenshot into the clipboard, I'm current using the following command in my i3 config:

```
bindsym Print       exec --no-startup-id maim /tmp/screenshot.png && cat /tmp/screenshot.png | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png
```

However, there are 2 problems with this:

1. This saves the screenshot to a file before piping it into the clipboard. Instead, I'd like it to save the image directly to the clipboard if possible.
2. By using `cat`, how the image is copied depends on the target to be copied to. For example, on Facebook, it's copied as an image in the chat box (which is fine), but the raw text is copied instead when I paste it to the "post" box. However, using `right_mouse_click -> Copy Image` on images don't give this problem at all.

I've looked at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1392580/copying-files-to-clipboard-from-shell) and tried using:

```
bindsym Print           exec --no-startup-id maim /tmp/screenshot.png && xclip -selection clipboard -t "$(file -b --mime-type "$img")" < /tmp/screenshot.png
```

... instead but still have the same "plain text" problem.

My desired behaviors:

1. When I take a screenshot, put the image directly into the clipboard without having to save it as a separate file.
2. When I copy an image, I want it as an image like doing `right_mouse_click -> Copy Image` rather than `cat` or `echo` some raw text data into the clipboard.

(I'd also like to be able to select an image (may be in `sxiv`) and copy/pipe that to the clipboard, but I'll save that for another question after this one.)

How do I create such an image copying behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a file. From `maim` README:

```
maim -s | xclip -selection clipboard -t image/png
```

`maim` writes to STDOUT by default, which you can pipe to xclip — no , no echo, and no files.